# Field _id is always 0

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I create a table with 3 fields (_id, nombre, telefono).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+
            KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRYMARY KEY, "+
            KEY_NOMBRE +" TEXT, "+
            KEY_TELEFONO +" TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(sql);

}
public void add(String nombre, String telefono, SQLiteDatabase database) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NOMBRE,nombre);
    values.put(KEY_TELEFONO,telefono);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

}
```

When I insert a record the _id always takes the value (0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the `CREATE TABLE` string: "PRYMARY" instead of "PRIMARY". Change it to:

```
  String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+
            KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
            KEY_NOMBRE +" TEXT, "+
            KEY_TELEFONO +" TEXT);";
```

Comment: I had an issue where I was getting 0 for _id. The error in my case was that **_id** was not the only column in the primary key. I had inadvertly added other columns e.g. I used `CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aisles (_id INTEGER , aisleshopref INTEGER , aisleorder INTEGER  DEFAULT 1000 , aislename INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (_id, aisleshopref, aisleorder, aislename)) ;` .